# Eclipse Outline View- how to hide deprecated methods

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated

How to hide the `@Deprecated` annotated methods from the Eclipse Outline view for Java or JavaEE?

Comment: Do you want to hide the actual annotation? I'm not sure I quite follow. :(

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is not possible. You can hide them only by commenting the method/field. If you don’t have wright access to the source then it is not possible.

Apart from the options provided in the view toolbar, You can also hide some method/field in general(not limited to deprecated) by applying the name filters. Check [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-views-filtering.htm) for more details.